# MQL5 CTrade Buy() function

Tags: mql5

I am new to MQL5. I used to develop a lot in MQL4 and now I am trying to get my code work in MQL5 too. For some reason it seems I can't get very simple things working like opening a Buy position. I am using something like this:

```
 CTrade m_trade 
 if (  PositionsTotal() == 0 )
       m_trade.Buy( 0.1, Symbol(), price, 0, 0 );
```

All I want is to open a Buy position with a lot size of `0.1`.

In the StrategyTester, it first opens a position with a lot size `0.1` (so far so good), but then after a while the position gets closed (don't know yet why its getting closed) and then a new Buy position gets opened with a lot size as huge as it can possibly be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whole code is needed (maybe you got some code from examples available in mt5 default temninal.

Answer (score 1):

### First:

Before going deeper, let's first also diagnose the situation a step better:

```
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
...

CTrade m_trade;
...

if (  PositionsTotal() == 0 )
{
      if (  !trade.Buy( 0.1, _Symbol ) )
      {
          //--- failure message
            Print( "The .Buy() method failed. The return-code = ",
                    trade.ResultRetcode(),
                   ". Code description: ",
                    trade.ResultRetcodeDescription()
                    );
      }
      else
      {
            Print( "The .Buy() method executed successfully. The return-code = ",
                    trade.ResultRetcode(),
                   " (",
                    trade.ResultRetcodeDescription(),
                   ")"
                    );
      }
}
```

### Next:

If the `Print()`-ed output above confirms the operation was successful, you may add more details to the **`.Buy()`** method and re-test:

```
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
...

CTrade m_trade;
...

double aVolume     = 0.1;
double aPoint      =       SymbolInfoDouble(  _Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT  );
double anAsk       =       SymbolInfoDouble(  _Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK    );
double aBid        =       SymbolInfoDouble(  _Symbol, SYMBOL_BID    );
int    aNumDigits  = (int) SymbolInfoInteger( _Symbol, SYMBOL_DIGITS );
double aLongOpen   =       SymbolInfoDouble(  _Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK    ),
       aLongSL     =       aBid - 1000 * aPoint,
            SL     =       NormalizeDouble( aLongSL, aNumDigits ),
       aLongTP     =       aBid + 1000 * aPoint,
            TP     =       NormalizeDouble( aLongTP, aNumDigits );

if (  !trade.Buy( aVolume, _Symbol, aLongOpen, SL, TP, "Does this work?" ) )
{ ... }
```

For going Short, `aShortOpen`, `anAsk`-based { `TP`, `SL` }-prices and symmetric edit changes apply.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "CTrade.PositionOpen" instead.

Sample:

```
 Ctrade ctrade;
 double dAsk = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK);

 bool bRet = ctrade.PositionOpen(_Symbol, ORDER_TYPE_BUY, 0.1, dAsk, 0, 0, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Simply Use Custom function To Execute Buy And Sell,

```
buy();  
sell();
```

it will buy / sell  0.01 lot by default, with stop loss 250 & take profit 115 points,

below is the whole custom function

```
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;

    void buy(double lot = 0.01, double take_profits = 115, double stop_loss = 250){
       
        double ask_sell = NormalizeDouble( SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK), _Digits );  
       
        double sl = ( ask_sell - stop_loss* _Point );
        double tp = (ask_sell + take_profits* _Point);
       
        trade.Buy( lot, NULL, ask_sell, sl, tp , NULL );  
    }  // buy


void sell(double lot = 0.01, double take_profits = 115, double stop_loss = 250){
       
        double bid_buy = NormalizeDouble( SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_BID), _Digits );  
       
        double sl = ( bid_buy + stop_loss* _Point );
        double tp = ( bid_buy - take_profits* _Point );
       
        trade.Sell( lot, NULL, bid_buy, sl, tp, NULL );   
    }
```

**How To Use**
step 1: Create filename.mqh
step 2: in you next EA or Script , just import it like step 3
step 3: #include "..\foldername\fileName.mqh"
step 4: buy();   -> to buy 0.01  step 5: buy(0.08); -> to buy 0.08 lots.

> Same goes for sell();  just 2 line in every ea or Script ,
>
> 1. import mqh file, which containing the code. to buy and sell
> 2. just type **buy()**; or **sell();**  or with custom lot ,  **buy(0.5);**  or **sell(0.04);**