# Sending short order, MQL5

Tags: mql5

So I am really new to programming in MQl5, I have a question about sending an order. So this is the `MqlTradeRequest`:

```
double TakeProfitOpenS, StoplossLine1S, StoplossLine2S;
   if(BreakoutShort) {TakeProfitOpenS=open; StoplossLine1S=(close-open)*2+close; StoplossLine2S=(close-open)*1.8+close;}
   else {TakeProfitOpenS=0; StoplossLine1S=0; StoplossLine2S=0;}
   
   //---    Defining the BounceShort 
   double BounceShort = StoplossLine1S <= close <= StoplossLine2S;   

   //---    Stoploss for short 
   double   slShort     =     Bid      >= (2.5*GCdif_EMA)+close;
   double   slShort1    =     close    > StoplossLine1S;
   
   //---    Take Profit for short 
   double   tpShort     =     TakeProfitOpenS;
   
   MqlTradeRequest request={};
      request.price        =     SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID);   // Short
      request.magic        =     EXPERT_MAGIC;                 // EA magic number so you can track trades 
      request.action       =     TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;            // Market order
      request.symbol       =     _Symbol;                     // Symbol 
      request.type         =     ORDER_TYPE_SELL;              // Long
//---    request.order        =     "OrderTicketSell";            // The orderticket so you can trace the individual trade 
      request.deviation    =     5;                            // Maximum price deviation 
      request.volume       =     0.25;                         // This should be €25.000 
      request.tp           =     tpShort;                      // Take profit Short 
      request.sl           =     (slShort || slShort1);        // Stoploss Short
      request.comment      =     "Sell using OrderSendAsync()";
   MqlTradeResult result={};
   if(!OrderSendAsync(request,result))
     {
      Print(__FUNCTION__,": error ", GetLastError(),", retcode = ", result.retcode);
     }
```

If this happens:

```
   double BreakoutS  =  BreakoutShort && GCRB < 200;
```

I want to open the trade, but I have no idea where to start. If someone could tell me how I can use this to actually send an order that would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i use custom function to execute buy and sell,

```
buy();
sell();
```

These will execute 0.01 lot by default , but you can execute it something like below,

```
buy(0.04);
sell(0.08);
```

any lots you want,

Whole Code Already Commented [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73996735/12218834) in this Question